# How to translate a Lightning Component Tab label in different languages?

Tags: lightning-web-components, translation, label

I wonder how to translate Lightning Component Tab label? Why custom tab is not available at Rename Tabs and Labels in Setup. There is any special step to acheive translation here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rename Tabs and Labels are only for *standard* translations. To translate custom configurations, including tabs, picklist values, etc, use the [Translation Workbench](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.workbench.htm&type=5) (Setup > User Interface > Translation Workbench > Translate).

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox - Web Tab insted of Listghtning Component Tab or Custom Tab was confusing for me. Translation changed. Thanks again for explanation.